# No access to port with easyPHP

Tags: php, port, fopen, easyphp

I can not access the port with easyPHP.

```
exec("mode com15: BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=1 to=off dtr=on rts=off");
$fp =fopen("com15", "w");
//$fp = fopen('/dev/ttyUSB0','r+'); //use this for Linux
sleep(5);
fwrite($fp,"1"); //write string to serial
sleep(5);
fclose($fp);
```

I want to send my COM15 port one 1 to turn an LED on Arduino.
When I'm under arduino, no worries.
But in php, I see the connection be nothing but then no reaction.
If someone has an idea. I dry it since yesterday.
Thank you in advance
Stéphane

Comment: when I run the page, I see the connection be as under with cmd mode.
So the connection is open.
Against it by not getting what I sent him

Comment: Try to use some serial terminal like rs232analyzer that will tell you if the problem is at the device or at the code.